# Does partition type affect HDDScan results?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I'm running HDDScan on my HDD, and I've already run into 70 000+ consecutive bad blocks. My HDD is split up into three partitions; two partitions that are compatible with Windows, and one that is not. I was wondering if these bad blocks are caused by a partition that Windows can't read, or if these bad blocks just mean I should replace the disk.

Thanks in advance for any answers.
- Harm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> I've already run into 70 000+ consecutive bad blocks.  ......   if
> these bad blocks just mean I should replace the disk.

I am somewhat surprised the disk is even working. Retrieve what you can and replace disk right away (today if you can).